# PyQGIS change attribute value with substring condition

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I have a code where I check and change all feature values if necessary according to the condition.
Is there an option to change a feature value if the string contains subtext? maybe with LIKE operator?
see first IF statement in code below.

original Code :

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
layer.startEditing()

if feature ['gebruiksdo'] == 'woonfunctie' and feature ['Wtype'] == 'Utiliteit' and feature ['cooperatie'] !=1 :
        layer.changeAttributeValue(feature.id(), layer.fields().indexFromName('DubbelF'),1)
    else:
        layer.changeAttributeValue(feature.id(), layer.fields().indexFromName('DubbelF'),0)
layer.commitChanges()
```

I want something like:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
layer.startEditing()

if feature ['gebruiksdo'] LIKE 'woon' and feature ['Wtype'] == 'Utiliteit' and feature ['cooperatie'] !=1 :
        layer.changeAttributeValue(feature.id(), layer.fields().indexFromName('DubbelF'),1)
    else:
        layer.changeAttributeValue(feature.id(), layer.fields().indexFromName('DubbelF'),0)
layer.commitChanges()
```

Comment: Try `if 'woon' in feature['gebruiksdo'].lower() and feature['Wtype'] == ...`.  I suggest using `.lower()` to still catch cases where the capitalisation may be different, 'WoonFunctie', for example.

Comment: LIKE is a SQL operator. For python see: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_strings.asp